# Using || in Cases in a Switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

So for a college lab for Java Fundamentals I'm having trouble. I have to set up a switch and inside that switch a case. There are 3 options for user input, and each option can be answered with letter. The problem is that this letter is allowed to be capital OR lower case, and the problem is I cant seem to figure out how to set it up so a case will allow either of those.

In the code below..crustType is defined as a char.

Keep in mind this is Java Fundamentals and we're just learning about switches, unfortunately our PPT for this doesn't explain what to do in this situation.

```
switch (crustType)
  {
     case (crustType == 'H' || crustType == 'h'):
        crust = "Hand-tossed";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Hand-Tossed' crust for your pizza.");
        break;

     case (crustType == 'T' || crustType == 't'):
        crust = "Thin-crust";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Thin-Crust' crust for your pizza.");
        break;

     case (crustType == 'D' || crustType == 'd'):
        crust = "Deep-dish";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Deep-Dish' crust for your pizza.");
        break;

     default:
        crust = "Hand-tossed";
        System.out.println("You have not selected a possible choice so a Hand-tossed crust was selected.");
  }
```

However I keep getting an error with ||...

```
97: error: incompatible types
      case (crustType == 'H' || crustType == 'h'):
                             ^   required: char   found:    boolean 
102: error: incompatible types
```

Comment: Either you can use use two separate case labels per case (a'la the answers), or `switch(Character.toUpperCase(crustType))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
case 'H':
case 'h':
    ...
    break;
case 'T':
case 't':
    ...
    break;
```

instead. Since the type of `crustType` is `char`, then what goes in `case`s must be of `char` type. When you put something like

```
crustType == 'H'
```

you will get an error because that expression returns a `boolean`.

Comment: This worked. I'll mark as my accepted answer when it allows me. Thank you. Thank all of you actually.

Answer (score 5):

It's wrong, Use like below

```
case 'H' :
case 'h' :
       crust = "Hand-tossed";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Hand-Tossed' crust for your pizza.");
        break;
// Next set code case
```

This is how a statement can have multiple case labels

Comment: No need for (crustType=='H') just use case 'H' :

Comment: Did what Kugathasan suggested, seems resolved so far. New error.

    97: error: incompatible types
         case (crustType == 'H'):
                         ^
  required: char
  found:    boolean
   98: error: incompatible types

Comment: @TheLostMInd : I copied the code from OP and paste it, before edit it, you down voted it.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - I first upvoted... and then removed my upvote after looking at the answer correctly.. I never downvoted.. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind, I was correcting the code, withing that peoples down voted it.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - Welcome to stackOverflow mate.. You'll love it... :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can use `if-else-if` statements

```
if(crustType == 'H' || crustType == 'h'){
        crust = "Hand-tossed";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Hand-Tossed' crust for your pizza.");
        }

     else if(crustType == 'T' || crustType == 't'){
        crust = "Thin-crust";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Thin-Crust' crust for your pizza.");
        }

     else if(crustType == 'D' || crustType == 'd'){
        crust = "Deep-dish";
        System.out.println("You have selected 'Deep-Dish' crust for your pizza.");
        }

     else{
        crust = "Hand-tossed";
        System.out.println("You have not selected a possible choice so a Hand-tossed crust 
was selected.");
}
```

or a `String.equalIgnoreCase` method in the if .

N.B. i would prefer the other answer .. it is just an alternative :)