# I have an error coming up on this line: case 1: boolean = (number % 7 == 0);

Tags: java

I have an error coming up on this line:

```
case 1: boolean = (number % 7 == 0);
```

Here is my whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
    number = input.nextInt();
    String numberString;

    switch (number) {
        case 1: boolean = (number % 7 == 0);
        System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
                break; 
        case 2: boolean = (number % 7 != 0); 
        System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
                break;
        default: 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What variable do you suppose you're assigning to?

Comment: That aside, what is this even supposed to do? You're switching on `number`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using || in Cases in a Switch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520252/using-in-cases-in-a-switch) That question also had something regarding putting boolean statements next to `case`.

Answer (score 3):

`boolean` is a type. It can't be used as a variable name. And variables have to be declared before being used.

So this would be valid code, for example:

```
boolean divisibleBy7 = (number % 7 == 0)
if (divisibleBy7) {
    System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
}
else {
    System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you misused the switch statement. I see, that you want to handle two different cases, but don't do this with a switch statement. `case 1` is only entered, if `number == 1` and `case 2` is entered if `number == 2`. For all other numbers the `default` case would be entered, which contains no code.

I think, what you want the code to do is something like this:

```
if (number % 7 == 0) {
    System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
} else {
    System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
}
```